# Issues with Postman Calls on API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm currently making an API from scratch, and I'm having issues getting a response from my POSTMAN calls. I've checked several articles on SO, and I haven't been able to find a solution. My code is the following:

```
@RestController
@Api(tags="Controller")
public class Controller {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);

@CrossOrigin
@ApiOperation(value = "test")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/c000/getpref/v1/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiImplicitParams({ @ApiImplicitParam(name = "client-metadata", value = "Client Metadata", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header") })
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = CinchyConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS_SUCCESSFUL_CODE, message = CinchyConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS_SUCCESSFUL),
                        @ApiResponse(code = CinchyConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS_BAD_REQUEST_CODE, message = CinchyConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS_BAD_REQUEST),
                        @ApiResponse(code = CinchyConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS_NOT_FOUND_CODE, message = CinchyConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS_NOT_FOUND),
                        @ApiResponse(code = CinchyConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR_CODE, message = CinchyConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR) })
public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
    LOGGER.debug("In test()");

    String test = "UWU";
    return ResponseEntity.ok(test);
}
```

}

The logger doesn't print the statement, and all I get from POSTMAN is the following:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-09-21T18:07:08.722+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/c000/getpref/v1/test"
}
```

I tried with and without headers, and both don't provide me with a solution. Does anyone have an idea about what the issue is?

Comment: Unless your spring-boot app is started in debug you wouldn't get that statement in your logs. Is your directory structure correct? Also not sure about all those `@Apixxx` annotations. But one way to debug is to remove all those *unnecessary* annotations and just keep the basic minimum ones till you get rid of the `404`. Once that's accomplished you could then go ahead and add all those annotations again. Also I don't think its an issue with *postman*, you wouldn't be able to hit that url from any browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

CinchyConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS_SUCCESSFUL_CODE is 200 ?
Also if you are expecting a response body, you should mention it for each status

```
    @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "I have a cool response", response = MyResponse.class),
      //......
     public ResponseEntity<?> test() {
       return new ResponseEntity<MyResponse>(new MyResponse("UWU"), HttpStatus.OK);
     }
```

and MyResponse simple code :

```
public class MyResponse{

    private String text;

    public MyResponse(String text) {
       this.text = text;
    }
    public String getText() {
       return text;
    }
 }
```

If you are starting the server with the default port, the GET to

```
 http://localhost:8080/c000/getpref/v1/test
```

should return your text in a json format. 
To be sure that your problem is connected to the code and not to postman configuration, please also try to access the link from browser.